# JavaScript dialog box / context menu for text areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project at the moment that requires a dialog box or context menu to display when the text in the box matches a certain regex pattern.

For example, if I was to type @user into the text area, a dialog box would show up where the cursor is or just below the typed word containing Ajax generated list of possible matched user names.

Are there any JavaScript packages (preferably a jQuery add-on) that will do this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) autocomplete plugin. Here is a site that lists 10 of them: http://webtecker.com/2008/03/10/10-auto-complete-ajax-scripts/

(Disclaimer: I have no relationship with this site.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

You might have to tweak it to match your requirements, but some of the basic functionality is there.

Comment: Is there a way to do this not using jQuery?

Comment: It's not too difficult to implement. Listen to the `keyup` event on the textbox, match the content of the textbox against a list of regexes and attach behaviors when you find a match. Basically :)